# Python Matplotlib - How to plot a graph from a table with 2 columns

Tags: python, matplotlib

If the table represented in a matrix (a table with 2 columns - y,x columns).

I want to represent the dots on the graph and then to draw a line connecting all the dots.
I didn't find an example for this simple need.
How to achieve it?

Comment: The first or second entry when search for *"matplotlib plot"* on google is the [pyplot tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html), where some examples are exactly about what you are asking for. Please note that questions like this, where obviously not a single attempt has been made to find a solution prior to asking are **not welcome** on Stackoverflow, as they draw attention away from questions with real problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As been pointed out in the comment, this information is already available online, with some googling. However, the provided link does not answer how to extract the data from a matrix. Further, there is no example showing the simplest way to plot a line with the data points marked out specifically. Therefore I provide this minimal example showing these two concepts:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as pp

M = np.array([[1., 1],
              [4, 2],
              [9, 3],
              [16, 4],
              [25, 5]])

x = M[:,1] # Extracting second column (x values)
y = M[:,0] # Extracting first column (y values)

# The third argument to plot describes the curve.
# o means that there should be dots for the data values
# - (single dash) means that there should be a connecting line
# As can be seen, these options can be combined.
pp.plot(x, y, 'o-')
pp.show()
```